# C# ASP.NET Retrieving file address in string

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am building a method that will build an XLS file and uploading it on user's computer.
I am using this guide:
http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-create-excel.htm

So code that will define my destination address is:

`xlWorkBook.SaveAs("C:\\Something\\csharp-Excel.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal);`

Now it is default, but i want to allow user to define it by him self, so as far as i understand, i need an html field, which will open common "browse window" and save file path to string, which will be later used in `xlWorkBook.SaveAs` function. I have read a bit about FileUpload, but i don't really sure that it is what i am looking for.

Comment: The user doesn't send you the file path, you send the file to the user and then they choose where to save it. Just like whenever you download a file from a website, I'm sure you've done it hundreds of times. Upload would be if the user sends you a file, not the other way round.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that you have there will save the file on the web server itself, not on the user's computer. You'll need to stream the file down to the user via the browser, and then they will be able to choose where to save it.

You could save the file on the server and then stream it to the user using Response.WriteFile, or you could stream it from memory if you don't want to keep a copy of the file on the server.

Comment: Sorry, I typed in almost the exact same answer as you at the same time.  You beat me to it by some seconds :)

Answer (score 1):

This code will create a file ***on the server***, not on the users/clients computer.  If you want the user to be able to download the file to his/her computer and select the location where the file is stored, you need to create a file (.aspx file or controller method, depending on wether you are using webforms or MVC) and have it stream the file to the user's browser.  The browser will then take care of displaying the "Save as" dialog where the user can select the destination location.